# Can someone cite a good reference for programming with exceptions?

Tags: design-patterns, exception, coding-style, throw, try-catch

I prefer to have the "rc" error-code return style of error management.  I agree that this presents challenges that are better served by throw-catch, however, I still feel that I am not designing and implementing in a style that is clean and maintainable.  So, I am looking for a good book that discusses the pattern and is not simply a reference book.

A bibliography of references would be fine too ...

An excerpt from the answer below, "Practices of an Agile Programmer", that I found especially striking:

```
**Keeping Your Balance**

• Determining who is responsible for handling an exception is part of design.
• Not all situations are exceptional.
• Report an exception that has meaning in the context of this code. A NullPointerException is pretty but just as useless as the null object described earlier.
• If the code writes a running debug log, issue a log message when an exception is caught or thrown; this will make tracking them down much easier.
• Checked exceptions can be onerous to work with. No one wants to call a method that throws thirty-one different checked exceptions. That’s a design error: fix it, don’t patch over it.
• Propagate what you can’t handle.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found a book dedicated to exception handling, but there are some which deal with this topic at the length of a section or chapter.

As a primer and for a language agnostic approach see *[Martin, Ch. 7]*. *[McConnel, Ch. 8.4]* also deals with exception handling on a very general basis. For addtionally good advices for the use of exceptions see *[Subramaniam, Hunt, Ch. 36, 37]*. I also found *[Richter, Ch. 20]* very useful although it is specific to .NET and C#. Nevertheless some sections are applicable to other languages, too.

Recommendation: As an alternative approach to throwing exceptions and error-code return style of programming, do some research on the "Special Case Pattern" or "Null Object Pattern" in the WWW.

- *[Martin]* Martin, C. R. (2008). Clean
  Code: A Handbook of Agile Software
  Craftsmanship. Prentice Hall
  International.
- *[McConnel]* McConnel,
  S. (2004). Code Complete.
- *[Subramaniam, Hunt]*
  Subramaniam, V., & Hunt, A. (2006).
  Practices of an Agile Developer.
  Pragmatic Programmers.
- *[Richter]*
  Richter, J. (2010). CLR via C#.
  Microsoft Press.

Comment: I have only checked the citation "Practices of an Agile Developer" and came away with some excellent guidelines along with a discussion with the scenario that is plaguing me.  Therefore, I think this is the starting point that I was looking for and awarded it to be the answer.  Over time I expect this to get further refined and validated.  - thanks Theo.

Comment: You should really check out [Martin], too. It describes the flaws of the return code style and contrast it with exception handling. [Martin] uses code examples to illustrate this very impressively. [Subramaniam, Hunt] is more on the level of practices than code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any book dealing specifically with best practices of exception throwing/usage.  It may be too specific a topic to warrant an entire book.  Also, best practices are likely to be vary significantly for each programming language (C++ vs. Java), as well as programming contexts within a language (C# winforms vs. C# asp.net).

I suspect your best bet is to google it; you'll likely find some blog posts that address the topic (hopefully, the best/most-respected ones will be near to top of google results).

Comment: Thanks moikemanne - actually, I posted the question after weeks of surfing while dealing with the monster.  I totally agree with your assessment about the specificity and that is likely the reason for my search with the community.